# Challenging Django queryset construction, filtering and sorting

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a website in Django where users make chat rooms and other users then visit the said chat rooms. Such chat rooms can be open to public, or private. The simple models are:

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    private = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class RoomTraffic(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    which_room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom)
    time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I get a listing of all **public** chat rooms (`chatroom.private='0'`), sorted by total unique visitors seen in the previous 60 mins? Those chat rooms that didn't see much (or any) action will be sorted last, those with the most action will be on top; ALL will be listed.

---

Tried the following, in vain:

```
date = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)
articles = ChatRoom.objects.filter(private='0').extra(select = {
  "views" : """
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myapp_roomtraffic
    JOIN myapp_chatroom on myapp_roomtraffic.which_room_id = myapp_chatroom.id
  WHERE myapp_roomtraffic.visitor_id = myapp_user.id
  AND myapp_roomtraffic.time > %s """ % date,
}).order_by("-views")
```

This simple returned an error: **syntax error at or near "00"** (where "00" was the datetime object inside extra)

Comment: Here's what I have tried, in vain: `date = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)`
`rooms = ChatRoom.objects.filter(private='0').extra(select={'uniques':'SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT visitor_id) FROM myapp_chatroom AS roomtraffic WHERE (roomtraffic.time > %s AND roomtraffic.which_group_id=roomtraffic.which_group_id)'},select_params=(date,),).order_by('-uniques')`

Comment: This gives me a: **syntax error at or near "SELECT"** (not much to go on)

Comment: Why is `private` not a `BooleanField`?

Comment: yep Kye, rewrote that, it's now a boolean. Wanna take a stab at the answer? :-)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use agregation functionality.
(called aggregate and annotate)
You can read about it here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

**Main idea is:**
You cant make somethink like a virtual field with a data that you collect(aggregate) on many other fields, and use that virtual field later, like other fields.

```
from django.db.models import Count

last_hour_delta = datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=1)

ChatRoom.objects.annotate(visitors_count=Count('room_traffic__visitor')).filter(private=False).filter(created_at__gt=last_hour_delta).order_by('-visitors_count')
```

p.s. i dont test this code. just a example.

Comment: This adds total count of non-unique visitors to each group, and then filters the groups via their date of creation. That's not what I want. I want to sort groups by the total unique visitors in the previous 1 hr (the groups could have been created at any point in the past).